# Infinite group with unique maximal subgroup

Tags: group-theory

If $G$ is a group, then by a maximal subgroup, we mean a proper subgroup, which is maximal w.r.t. subset(subgroup) relation.

It is well known that a finite group with unique maximal subgroup must be cyclic.

Is there an infinite group with unique maximal subgroup?

Comment: I was thinking about $\mathbb{Q}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: It actually looks good.

Comment: The group $Z_{p^{\infty}} \times C_p$ for $p$ a prime is an example with unique maximal subgroup $Z_{p^{\infty}} \times \{1\}$. see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/777441/does-gamma-infinite-p-group-m-one-of-its-maximal-subgroup-imply-gamm for the details.